# JS - Transform an Object into an Array unless it is an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's say we have to iterate over either an `Object` or an `Array of Objects`. I want to transform the Object into an array of one object and then iterate in my React App, to present what I want.

Let' take an example:

```
// Returned value as object
const zoo = {
  lion: '',
  panda: '',
};

// I want to transform it into Array of 1 Object
const zoo = [{
  lion: '',
  panda: '',
}];
```

How could I achieve that, but only if the returned value is not already an array?

Answer (score 7):

Just check if it is an array. If not, convert it:

```js
return Array.isArray(zoo) ? zoo : [zoo];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function handleObj(obj){
return Array.isArray(obj)?obj:[obj]
}

console.log(handleObj({label:'aa',value:1}))
```